# Query to select and alternate records from 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm trying to optimize some queries in a *duplicate finder* application in PHP CodeIgniter. And in order to keep the MVC pattern and stay away from DB calls directly in the views or controllers, I'm looking for a query that will *alternate* results from 2 different tables:

**Table** `duplicate_leads`

```
╔════╦══════════════╦═══════════╦════════════════════╦═══════════╗
║ id ║ original_id  ║    name   ║       email        ║   phone   ║
╠════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║      345     ║   Stack   ║ stack@overflow.com ║ 0000-0000 ║
║  2 ║      495     ║ Exchange  ║ stack@exchange.com ║ 0000-0000 ║
╚════╩══════════════╩═══════════╩════════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

**Table** `leads`

```
╔═════╦═══════════╦════════════════════╦═══════════╗
║ id  ║    name   ║       email        ║   phone   ║
╠═════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 345 ║   Stack   ║ stack@overflow.com ║ 0000-0000 ║
║ 495 ║ Exchange  ║ stack@exchange.com ║ 0000-0000 ║
╚═════╩═══════════╩════════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

The `duplicate_leads.original_id` is the value that relates the lead to the original lead's `leads.id`.

## Attempt #1

```sql
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.name,
    a.email,
    a.phone
FROM
    leads a
        JOIN duplicate_leads b
            ON a.id = b.original_id
```

Which produces:

```
╔═════╦═══════════╦════════════════════╦═══════════╗
║ id  ║    name   ║       email        ║   phone   ║
╠═════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 345 ║   Stack   ║ stack@overflow.com ║ 0000-0000 ║
║ 495 ║ Exchange  ║ stack@exchange.com ║ 0000-0000 ║
║ ... ║    ...    ║         ...        ║    ...    ║
╚═════╩═══════════╩════════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Seems to be retrieving records from one of the two tables. I don't have advanced experience in SQL so I don't know how exactly use the joins or unions for this particular case because I think that either way, what the query will return is a kind-of concatenation of result like this:

```
╔═════╦═══════════╦════════════════════╦═══════════╗
║ id  ║    name   ║       email        ║   phone   ║
╠═════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 345 ║   Stack   ║ stack@overflow.com ║ 0000-0000 ║
║ 495 ║ Exchange  ║ stack@exchange.com ║ 0000-0000 ║
║     ║   Stack   ║ stack@overflow.com ║ 0000-0000 ║
║     ║ Exchange  ║ stack@exchange.com ║ 0000-0000 ║
╚═════╩═══════════╩════════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

**What I'm actually expecting:**
The rows shown first (because they could be multiple) should be records from the `leads` table. These records should be the ones that match the `original_id` of the `duplicate_leads` which should be the next row after the ones matched, like so:

```
╔═════╦═══════════╦════════════════════╦═══════════╗
║ id  ║    name   ║       email        ║   phone   ║
╠═════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 345 ║   Stack   ║ stack@overflow.com ║ 0000-0000 ║ from leads
║     ║   Stack   ║ stack@overflow.com ║ 0000-0000 ║ from duplicate_leads
║ 495 ║ Exchange  ║ stack@exchange.com ║ 0000-0000 ║ from leads
║     ║ Exchange  ║ stack@exchange.com ║ 0000-0000 ║ from duplicate_leads
║ ... ║    ...    ║         ...        ║    ...    ║
╚═════╩═══════════╩════════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Multiple matches example:

```
╔═════╦═══════════╦════════════════════╦═══════════╗
║ id  ║    name   ║       email        ║   phone   ║
╠═════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 345 ║   Stack   ║ stack@overflow.com ║ 0000-0000 ║ from leads
║ 677 ║   Stack   ║ stack@overflow.com ║ 0000-0000 ║ from leads
║     ║   Stack   ║ stack@overflow.com ║ 0000-0000 ║ from duplicate_leads
║ 495 ║ Exchange  ║ stack@exchange.com ║ 0000-0000 ║ from leads
║     ║ Exchange  ║ stack@exchange.com ║ 0000-0000 ║ from duplicate_leads
║ ... ║    ...    ║         ...        ║    ...    ║
╚═════╩═══════════╩════════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

How can I achieve that result?

## Update

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d87a9/1

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry I know is not the best MCVE that you will ever see, but I included the query I built after researching, the result I get with that query and what is my desired result.

Comment: It doesn't need to be the best. It just needs to be as good as all the others.

Answer (score 1):

You want to write this I believe:

```
SELECT
a.id,
a.name
a.email
FROM leads a
UNION ALL
SELECT
a.id,
a.name
a.email
FROM leads a
INNER JOIN duplicate_leads b
ON a.id = b.original_id
ORDER BY a.id
```

The first query (before the union) will give you one row for every record in your leads table

The second query will give you one row for every lead in your duplicates table (given that it has a match in the lead table - which it should if everything is set-up correctly), but will display the info for the record in the leads table for which the match is found.

The ORDER BY then helps you visualize this so all rows are grouped according to the original lead id

The important thing to remember is that joining two tables creates one table with all the columns from both tables (you then trim down which columns are displayed using SELECT). With a standard join, all of the fields from the original table are maintained, and if a match is found in the second table, these fields will be populated as well. Otherwise, they'll be null.

This is why your original query was only giving you one row per lead. If you SELECT *, you'll get a better idea what's going on behind the scenes

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT id, name, email, phone
FROM (
    SELECT l.id, l.name, l.email, l.phone, dl.original_id
    FROM leads AS l
    JOIN duplicate_leads AS dl
        ON dl.original_id = l.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL AS id, dl.name, dl.email, dl.phone, dl.original_id
    FROM leads AS l
    JOIN duplicate_leads AS dl
        ON dl.original_id = l.id
) AS leads_combined
ORDER BY original_id ASC, id > 0 DESC, id ASC;
```

should be closer to what you asked for. I've merged my previous query with the `JOIN` from Daniel Long's answer, to only find leads that have duplicates, and ordering the leads before the duplicates in the results.

Comment: Thank you, @astrangeloop! This one seems to be closer, but it also returns all the records from `leads` even when there's no `duplicate_lead.original_id` that matches the `lead.id`. I added more details to the question and a SQL Fiddle :)

Comment: I've updated my answer - hope this is closer to what you mean. It would be good to have a little more data in the SQL Fiddle, including #677 in your example.